# MATLAB: switch statement problems

Tags: matlab, parsing, switch-statement

I am trying to parse a certain file.

My idea was to read line after line while using switch sentence.
I need to compare first word in line with certain strings.

```
     log = fopen('my_file');
     tline = fgetl(log);

     while ischar(tline)
          split = strsplit(tline,',');
          switch split(1)
                case 'str1'
                %do something
                case 'str2'
                %do something else
          end      
     end
```

I keep getting "SWITCH expression must be a scalar or
string constant."

Class of split and split(1) is char. The variable is constant in each loop of while.

What is wrong?

Comment: Looking at the question more closely, did MATLAB say the class of `split(1)` is char (i.e., `class(split(1)) == char`)?  Because if that is the case, my answer is moot.

Comment: @TroyHaskin: I'm pretty sure that assertion in the question is incorrect, or at least incomplete (maybe "cell array containing `char`-typed cells")

Comment: Yes, class(split(1)) == char.

But it works now, thanks!

Comment: @bmr Not to belabor the point, but a cell array referenced with parentheses should be of class `cell` while referencing with curly braces should be of class `char` if that cell contains a string (or `double` if it is a number, etc.).  I think it is important to appreciate that difference.

Comment: @bmr Also, glad to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) returns a cell array of strings.  You need to access the contents of the result using the curly braces:

```
switch split{1}
    case 'str1'
    %do something
    case 'str2'
    %do something else
end
```